# Is there a way to make VBA as a standard open PowerShell 7.3.6.0?

Tags: vba, powershell, powershell-7.0

Running the following VBA code opens PowerShell v1, and computes size remaining on DriveLetter C.

```
Sub RunPowershell()
    Set wShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    Set wShellResult = wShell.Exec("powershell (Get-Volume -DriveLetter C).SizeRemaining")
    ' Change to StdErr.ReadAll to read an error response
    MsgBox wShellResult.StdOut.ReadAll
End Sub
```

Is there a way to make VBA open PowerShell 7.3.6.0 when it's called in VBA?

Thanks in advance

I tried specifying the version number in the vba code

Comment: Use the full pathname : C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe

Answer (score 0):

Newer Powershell is started with `pwsh`, rather than `powershell`. It is located in C:\Program Files\PowerShell\7, but it will probably work fine without a full path.